# How to add submenu in Qt

Tags: qt, qt4

How do I add a submenu from the menu below? I need a submenu to open, say, after clicking

```
"A->Setup"
```

I want a submenu to be opened to the side of the main menu.

```
   void MyMenu::cppSlot()
        {
            QMenu *xmenu = new QMenu;
            xmenu->addMenu("A -> Setup");
            xmenu->addMenu("B -> Setup");
            xmenu->addMenu("C -> Setup");
            xmenu->addMenu("D -> Setup");
            xmenu->addMenu("E -> Setup");
            //Change font and width
            xmenu->setFont(QFont ("Courier", 10));
            xmenu->setFixedWidth(250);
            //Colour setting
            xmenu->setAutoFillBackground(true);
            /*QPalette palette=xmenu->palette();
            palette.setColor(QPalette::Window, Qt::black);
            palette.setColor(QPalette::Window, Qt::text);
            palette.color(green)
            xmenu->setPalette(palette);*/

            // Align the menu coordinates
           // xmenu->
            xmenu->move(900,300);

            xmenu->show();


        }
```

Comment: You need to add action to created submenus. If menu is empty it will not appear

Answer (score 36, accepted):

[QMenu::addMenu(const QString &title)](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qmenu.html#addMenu-1) returns a pointer to the created submenu. You can use these pointers to add actions for the submenus.

The following code:

```
QMenu *xmenu = new QMenu();
QMenu* submenuA = xmenu->addMenu( "A" );
QMenu* submenuB = xmenu->addMenu( "B" );
QMenu* submenuC = xmenu->addMenu( "C" );
QMenu* submenuD = xmenu->addMenu( "D" );
QMenu* submenuE = xmenu->addMenu( "E" );
QAction* actionA_Setup = submenuA->addAction( "Setup" );
QAction* actionB_Setup = submenuB->addAction( "Setup" );
QAction* actionC_Setup = submenuC->addAction( "Setup" );
QAction* actionD_Setup = submenuD->addAction( "Setup" );
QAction* actionE_Setup = submenuE->addAction( "Setup" );
```

*(Hint: This cries for a loop)*

will produce a menu like this:

[image: Screenshot of the created menu]

You can then connect slots to the `triggered()` signal of the returned actions (e.g. `actionA_Setup`).