# How to properly add a QMenu (and submenu) using a QAction

Tags: qt, c++11, qt5, qmenu, qmenubar

I have been trying to add a submenu to a `QMenu` via `QAction` but it is not working.
As you can see below I am able to see the choices via right click on a `QTableWidget`.
However from the menu "Option" I should see the submenu, but I don't see it.

[image: menu]

Below the procedure:

**rostreewidget.h**

```
    class ROSTreeWidget : public QTreeWidget
    {
        Q_OBJECT

    public:
        ROSTreeWidget(QWidget *parent = nullptr);
    signals:
        void selectFrom();
        void editLaserTable();

    private:
        QAction *mActionSELECT_FROM;
        QAction *mActionEditLaserTable;
        QAction *mAddMenu;

        QActionGroup *actions1, *actions2;

        QMenu *mMenu;
        QMenu *submenu;
        QAction *actionA_Setup;


    };
```

**rostreewidget.cpp**

```
// Namespace ROSLaserItemTree
ROSTreeWidget::ROSTreeWidget(QWidget *parent) : QTreeWidget(parent)
{
    mActionSELECT_FROM = new QAction(QIcon("/home/mapper/execute-command"), "SELECT * FROM", this);
    mActionEditLaserTable = new QAction(QIcon(":"), "Edit LaserScan Table");
    mAddMenu = new QAction(QIcon(":"), "Options", this);

    addActions({ mActionSELECT_FROM,
                 mActionEditLaserTable,
                 mAddMenu});

    connect(mActionSELECT_FROM, &QAction::triggered, [&]() {
        emit selectFrom();
    });

    connect(mActionEditLaserTable, &QAction::triggered, [&]() {
        emit editLaserTable();
    });

    connect(mAddMenu, &QAction::triggered, [&]() {
        mMenu = new QMenu();
        submenu = mMenu->addMenu( "A" );
        QAction* actionA_Setup = submenu->addAction( "Setup" );
    });
}
```

What I have done so far:

**1)** After following [this source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13799033/how-to-add-submenu-in-qt) I was able to prepare the menu and the submenu to be inserted in the `QAction` but unfortunately it is not working.
As you can see from the print screen I am not able to see the choices under "Option".

**2)** Another thing I tried was going through [this other source](http://zetcode.com/gui/qt5/menusandtoolbars/) which was also clear, but still I could not figure out why the submenu is not being added in the `QAction`.

Thanks for pointing to the right direction for solving this issue.

Comment: The problem is that you did Ctrl+C -> Ctrl+V without changes. Change `xmenu` to `mMenu` in your lambda.

Comment: @MaximSkvortsov, thanks for stopping by and reading the question. I corrected the code but still nothing happens. I updated the question. Do you see something I don't see?

Comment: Ok I figured it out! at the end of the menu definition I was missing `mMenu->exec()` Everything works fine now! Thanks for your time in stopping by and reading the question!