# QMenu (and submenu) opens up in a different monitor location

Tags: qt, c++11, qt5, qmenu, qaction

I built an application that uses `QMenu` and its related submenu. The `Qmenu` is triggered to open via `QAction`.

**The problem** I have is that as soon as I call the `QAction` and I chose the `QAction` that carries the "Options", it should open the `QMenu`, but **instead** the `QMenu` open in another location of the application looking totally detached.

Below is the **wrong** behavior, where it is possible to see the `QMenu` opening in another location of the Desktop.

[image: worng]

Here is the **expected** behavior where the `QMenu` opens up after selecting "Oprions":

[image: correct]

I am not sure of why this is happening.
Below the snippet of code related:

**rostreewidget.h**

```
    class ROSTreeWidget : public QTreeWidget
    {
        Q_OBJECT

    public:
        enum ROSType {
            NULLPTR,
            TABLE,
            BASE,
            MENU
        };

        ROSTreeWidget(QWidget *parent = nullptr);
        ROSType rostype(ROSTreeItem *rosItem) const;
        ROSType rostype() const {
            return rostype(currentItem());
        }

    signals:
        void selectFrom();
        void editLaserTable();

    private:
        QAction *mActionSELECT_FROM;
        QAction *mActionEditLaserTable;
        QAction *mAddMenuOptions;

        QMenu *submenuLaserScanA;
        QAction *submenuActionA, *submenuActionB, *submenuActionC;
        QMenu *submenuLaserScanB;
        QAction *submenuActionAA, *submenuActionBB, *submenuActionCC;
        QMenu *submenuLaserScanC;
        QAction *submenuActionAAA, *submenuActionBBB, *submenuActionCCC;

    };
```

**rostreewidget.cpp**

```
ROSTreeWidget::ROSTreeWidget(QWidget *parent) : QTreeWidget(parent)
{
    mActionSELECT_FROM = new QAction(QIcon(":"), "SELECT * FROM", this);
    mActionEditLaserTable = new QAction(QIcon(":"), "Edit LaserScan Table");
    mAddMenuOptions = new QAction(QIcon(":"), "Options", this);

    addActions({ mActionSELECT_FROM,
                 mActionEditLaserTable,
                 mAddMenuOptions});

    connect(mActionSELECT_FROM, &QAction::triggered, [&]() {
        emit selectFrom();
    });

    connect(mActionEditLaserTable, &QAction::triggered, [&]() {
        emit editLaserTable();
    });

    connect(mAddMenuOptions, &QAction::triggered, [&]() {
        mMenu = new QMenu();

        submenuLaserScanA = mMenu->addMenu( "Menu A" );
        mMenu->addSeparator();

        submenuLaserScanB = mMenu->addMenu( "Menu B" );
        mMenu->addSeparator();

        submenuLaserScanC = mMenu->addMenu( "Menu C" );
        submenuActionAAA = submenuLaserScanC->addAction("Setup C" );
        submenuActionBBB = submenuLaserScanC->addAction( "Setup C" );

        mMenu->show();
    });
}
```

What I have done so far:

1. After following [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13799033/how-to-add-submenu-in-qt) source I was able to prepare the menu and the submenu to be inserted in the `QAction` and in fact all the related settings about it are as I need them to be.
2. I thought that linking the `QAction` inside the lambda function, exactly as I did for the other choices, would have worked, but instead what I am obtaining as soon as I launch the application is a `QMenu` that opens in another location of the Desktop without being linked to the main choice as shown below.
3. According to the documentation [QMenu::addMenu](https://doc.qt.io/archives/qt-4.8/qmenu.html#addMenu-2) parameters set are correct, so what is going on?

Thanks for pointing to the right direction for solving this issue.

Comment: `mMenu = new QMenu();` You specified no parent. Have you tried using your "Options" widget as the parent?

Comment: Hello @NikosC. and thanks for stopping by and read the question :) . How do you suggest I solve the problem? Could you please provide some code as answer so that I better understand your suggestion?

Comment: try mMenu->exec(QCursor::pos()); instead of mMenu->show

Comment: @samdavydov, :) Thanks! That works great! thanks for stopping by and reading the question. I spent the past 3 hours figuring it out! If you write the answer I can accept it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this as a general pattern:

```
{
    QMenu menu;
    
    menu.addAction(...);
    menu.addAction(...);
    
    menu.exec(QCursor::pos()); // exec returns a triggered QAction
    // process action
}
```

`QMenu::exec()` is modal. You don't need a QMenu instance outside the function.